# Uncaught ReferenceError: request is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

```
$dd = "<a href='javascript:void(0);' id='requestsend$send_id' onClick='request($send_id,request_send);' class='post-add-icon inline-items'><button type='button' style='background: #ccc;' class='btn btn-add-frnd'  data-toggle='tooltip' title='request' data-original-title='Mark as read'>send</button></a>";
```

I getting like this :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: request is not defined
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

I expected this:

```
<a href='javascript:void(0);' id='requestsend$send_id' onClick='request("5","request_send");' class='post-add-icon inline-items'><button type='button' style='background: #ccc;' class='btn btn-add-frnd' data-toggle='tooltip' title='request' data-original-title='Mark as read'>send</button></a>
```

but got this:

```
<a href='javascript:void(0);' id='requestsend$send_id' onClick='request(5,request_send);' class='post-add-icon inline-items'><button type='button' style='background: #ccc;' class='btn btn-add-frnd' data-toggle='tooltip' title='request' data-original-title='Mark as read'>send</button></a>
```

Comment: do you have a request() function defined in your DOM in javascript?

Comment: It looks like `request` function being called on click is not defined.

Comment: <a href='javascript:void(0);' id='requestsend5' onClick='request("5","request_send");' class='post-add-icon inline-items'><button type='button' style='background: #ccc;' class='btn btn-add-frnd'  data-toggle='tooltip' title='request' data-original-title='Mark as read'>send</button></a>

i want get output in server side

Comment: <a href='javascript:void(0);' id='requestsend5' onClick='request(5,request_send);' class='post-add-icon inline-items'><button type='button' style='background: #ccc;' class='btn btn-add-frnd' data-toggle='tooltip' title='request' data-original-title='Mark as read'>send</button></a>

but got like this

Comment: Update the QUESTION instead of posting code in a comment

Comment: Why not have `onClick='request("$send_id","request_send");'` ?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$send_id' (T_VARIABLE) i got error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code:

```
 <a href='javascript:void(0);' id='requestsend$send_id' onClick='request(&#39 $send_id &#39, &#39 request_send &#39);' class='post-add-icon inline-items'><button type='button' style='background: #ccc;' class='btn btn-add-frnd' data-toggle='tooltip' title='request' data-original-title='Mark as read'>send</button></a>
```